# Python - No existe el servidor SQL Server o se ha denegado el acceso al mismo

Tags: python, sql-server

El siguiente `string` de conexión conecta perfectamente con el servidor destino:

```
Import pyodbc
cnn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer;DATABASE=MyDb;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx')
Print ("Conectado")
```

Pero cuando trato de conectarme a una instancia de ese servidor

```
Import pyodbc
cnn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=MyServer\MyInstance;DATABASE=MyDb;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx')
print ("Conectado")
```

Me arroja el error:

> Error: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server
>   Driver][DBNETLIB]No existe el servidor SQL Server o se ha denegado el
>   acceso al mismo. (17) (SQLDriverConnect)')

El punto es que debo acceder a esa instancia de la base de datos para trabajar con las tablas de prueba que esta tiene.

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: ¿Has intentado acceder a esa instancia usando SSMS con los mismos valores? ¿Funciona allí?

Comment: @sstan, gracias por el comentario. Si lo intenté y efectivamente me permite el acceso, pero ya lo logré solucionar: Resulta que cuando ingreso vía SSMS el nombre de la instancia lo escribo en minúscula y no hay problema, pero Python si es susceptible a Mayúsculas y Minúsculas. Simplemente escribí el nombre de la instancia en mayúscula y problema resuelto.

Comment: Hola Felipe. Ese es un dato interesante en cuanto a la forma como funciona diferente desde Python. Si tienes un tiempo, te sugiero de agregar una respuesta a tu pregunta y aceptarla. Seguramente será de ayuda a otros que experimenten lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente logré solucionar: Resulta que cuando ingreso vía SSMS el nombre de la instancia lo escribo en minúscula y no hay problema, pero Python si es susceptible a Mayúsculas y Minúsculas. Simplemente escribí el nombre de la instancia en mayúscula y problema resuelto